# Is it possible to debug the PHP source code (in C) while feeding it specific PHP scripts on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I would like to be able to debug the PHP source while running specific scripts in order to see what PHP does with the script internally and thus learn how PHP works "under the hood". How can I configure this workflow?

Comment: Using gdb perhaps on Linux, but no idea on Windows.... you'd have to build it from source on Windows to enable any kind of debugging

Comment: @MarkBaker On Windows, the debugger is built into the system (*kernel32.dll*). Any process is enabled for debugging. You don't need to build from source to gain the ability to debug (although you can improve the experience in case the vendor doesn't ship debug symbols). To OP: You learn how PHP works under the hood by writing C code. And you'll learn a lot of other valuable things when learning C as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug into internal c code of PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506007/how-to-debug-into-internal-c-code-of-php)

Comment: @Quolonel Questions, just to make this issue clearly, how do you want to really debug it? Do you use the VS IDE with PHP Tools for Visual Studio or the VS code or others?

Comment: I do not currently use anything. I am open to suggestion.

Comment: I know that developers could debug PHP project in VS DIE using the specific extension tool here. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5, but I'm not very sure that whether you want to debug it during developing or others using the VS IDE. Of course, it also has other debugger tools which supports the PHP: http://www.ttkalec.com/blog/debugging-php-visual-studio-style/